# Why can't I enter the while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
class Labo21
{
    public static void main(String [] arguments){
        int n;
        int i;
        double somme;

        System.out.print("Positive number: ");
        n = Clavier.lireInt(); //keyboard

        if( n <= 0){
            System.out.print("ERROR");
        }else{
            i = 2;
            somme = 1;

            while (n <= i){
                somme = somme + 1.0 / i;
                i = i + 1;
            }
            System.out.print("Result: " + somme);
        }
    }
}
```

I try to know why I cannot enter the while loop.

Comment: You need to use a debugger and check what `n` variable is. Probably it is lower than 2. Anyway, this question is off topic to SO since you want someone to debug your code.

Comment: You can enter the while loop. Just input something greater than 0 and less than or equal to 2. Also, this will result in an infinite loop since `n` will always be less than `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has a problem with its mentality. You are lucky that it is not going into the loop though. If it so, it would run without stopping and you cannot understand it.

BECAUSE: in your code you say the condition of while loop is i should be equal to or greater than n. I guess Clavier.lireInt(); getting value from user. So if user enters 1 condition will be while( 1 <= 2) then it will go through the while loop. Increment the i, then i will be 3 again greater than n, increment i then 4 will be greater than n. It will go like that.

I thing your condition should be :

```
while(n>=i)
```

Then you can enter n as 5 and count i = 2 to 5.

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Provide 1 or 2 as `Clavier.lireInt()` and you will go inside the loop.

Example :

```
class Labo21 {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        int n;
        int i;
        double somme;
        System.out.print("Positive number: ");
        n = 1; //Clavier.lireInt(); //keyboard
        if (n <= 0) {
            System.out.print("ERROR");
        } else {
            i = 2;
            somme = 1;
            while (n <= i) {
                System.out.println("in loop");
                somme = somme + 1.0 / i;
                i = i + 1;
            }
            System.out.print("Result: " + somme);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your number needs to be greater than 0 based on your `if` condition. To get into the `while` loop, your number needs to be less than or equal to 2 since you set `i` equal to 2. So your options are `1` or `2`.

With that being said, once you're inside the `while` loop, you will never be able to exit (you have created an infinite loop) because `n` will always be less than `i`. Your `i` is incrementing by 1 on each loop iteration, and `n` is never changing, so it will never be greater than `i`. You should add a terminating condition (some way to exit the loop).